# Is the phrase "over and out" contradictory?

Tags: terminology

Looking at [Voice Procedure terms on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_procedure#Words_in_voice_procedure) has left me a bit confused:

> Out — I have finished talking to you and **do not expect a reply**.
>
> Over — I have finished talking and I am **listening for your reply**. Short for "Over to you."

I've certainly heard the phrase, "Roger, over and out," used in Hollywood and general pop culture, but given what I've read it seems like both terms contradict each other. You wouldn't be listening for a reply if you did not expect one.

Comment: I think it's more redundant than contradictory. I'm done, please confirm that you're done, too.

Comment: This phrase is a relic of a different area, and even in that era radiotelephone operators just said "out" (not "over and out").

Comment: "over" doesn't mean "over to you", but rather "my unit of speech is over". (In half-duplex communication it indicates "I have finished speaking and switched my unit from transmit to receive").

Comment: It's what they said on *Highway Patrol* and other TV shows of the 50s ("10-4" was another favorite), so it *must* be correct.

Comment: I've always thought it was just a mistake.

Comment: Try _over_ = _end of this particular 'paragraph' of mine_ and _out_ = _message over; communication now being broken by me'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the definitions given in Wikipedia, these do seem contradictory. A quick look at [page 42 of a Civil Aviation Authority manual](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP41320Editionto4April2013_ISBN9780117928206.pdf) (a source listed on Wikipedia) also seems to offer conflicting definitions:

> OUT* This exchange of transmissions is ended and no response is
>   expected.
>
> OVER* My transmission is ended and I expect a response from you.

My guess would be that "over and out" is a phrase coined and popularized by Hollywood, rather than through true usage.

Comment: Hello, MeltingCity, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer is interesting—and potentially very good—but at the moment it requires the reader to negotiate a PDF of the Civil Aviation Authority manual. Your answer would be stronger (and more convenient to read) if you quoted the relevant sentence(s) of the manual as an extract (block quote) in your answer, retaining the link for readers who might want to see the manual's full treatment. If you make that addition, I'll happily upvote your answer. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that the general lingo was used by many groups besides aviation.  The police, in particular, used variants of the lingo (and likely different variants in different parts of the country).  I have little doubt that "over and out" was used *somewhere*.

Comment: @SvenYargs I can't find the evidence for it, but I feel sure it relates to a particular early radio transmission device which had a lever which was pushed *over* to a different position to switch from speaking to listening  mode. To end the call completely the lever was pushed outwards. Hence the terms *over* and *out* were used to confirm to the other party that a) you had finished talking and were switching to listening, and then b)that you were terminating the call altogether.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thank you for the welcome and the advice! I have included quotes from the manual I cited.

Comment: @HotLicks [This](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/over-and-out) partly deals with it, but I'm certain it is not the full story.

Comment: @WS2: If you locate something definite, I hope you'll post it as an answer. I remember an old TV show from the early 1960s in which Andy Griffith (playing the fictional sheriff of Mayberry, North Carolina) is communicating on some kind of two-way radio box with a bigshot state police investigator, and he says "over and out" and flicks something on the box; but whether that was a verité reenactment of contemporaneous police radio procedure or an exercise in Hollywood hoowee, I don't know.

Comment: @SvenYargs [This](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/over-and-out) touches on it, but does not explain it either well or fully.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who received both military and aviation Radio Procedure training I can assure you that they are indeed contradictory, and that real radio operators are trained not to use the phrase. The phrase is a product of Hollywood (and perpetuated by those whose only radio procedure training comes from Hollywood). This fact is usually taught to radio operators in the first hour of their training.

The correct usage is exactly that stated in the question. [Wikipedia is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_procedure#Words_in_voice_procedure). [The UK Civil Aviation Authority is right (Chapter 2 Page 5).](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP41320Editionto4April2013_ISBN9780117928206.pdf)

TLDR:

- **Over** — I have finished talking and I am listening for your reply.
- **Out** — I have finished talking to you and do not expect a reply.
- **Over and Out** - incorrect procedure.

Answer (score 1):

My father served as a radio operator, 30th Signal Corps, 76th Division, 3rd Army...European Theatre, WW2. "Over and out " in the movies drove him to cuss. You used one or the other.